# React Parent waiting for React Child Component update

Tags: reactjs

I have a third party child component which renders a table.
The parent component will render the child component with new data in props.
The parent will then use jquery selectors to select the rows from the child table that were thus rendered in this manner.
How can I get the parent to wait for the child component to render itself with the rows for the new data before it does the jquery row selection?
As the child is a third party component, I can't modify it to let the parent know when it's rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the appropriate  [lifecycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods)  to figure out when it's ready.
You can have *componentDidMount* send back a value telling the parent it's ready to be parse.

If you cannot edit the third-party component.. Check if there's available public method that you can use? Maybe it accepts a callback function as a prop?

Comment: componentDidUpdate should do it - so long as the third-party component is not doing anything asynchronous itself. componentDidMount is called on the parent after the children, so that would also do what's needed so long as it's only the initial render that's important (use componentDidUpdate for anything after that).

Comment: I was finding that the child was not rendering the html table at the time the I was in the parent's componentDidUpdate.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to workaround this by adding a mouse listener on the table itself and then using jquery's delegate method to route the click requests to the table rows.